# ListBox doesn't refresh after property changed

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox

I'm trying to bind two `ListBox`es:

```
<ListBox SelectionChanged="lbApplications_SelectionChanged"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Applications, 
                       UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" />
<ListBox DisplayMemberPath="Message" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Events, 
                       UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

`Applications` and `Events` are public properties in `Window` class.

I set `DataContext` to `this` to both list boxes and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `Window` class:

```
 private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
 {
   if (PropertyChanged != null)
     PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
 }
```

And then after adding new item to `Applications` or `Events` I call:

```
 NotifyPropertyChanged("Events");
 NotifyPropertyChanged("Applications");
```

The issue is that `ListBox` is loaded only one time. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's just look at one of the ListBoxes, since they're both the same, basically.

The code we're concerned about is this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Applications, 
                           UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Since you're new to WPF, let me say you probably don't need `UpdateSourceTrigger` or `Mode` in there, which leaves us with this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Applications}" />
```

You mentioned that Applications is a public property in your code-behind. You need it to be a `DependencyProperty`, and you need it to fire events when it changes -- most people use an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) for this.

So your code-behind will have something *like* this:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Applications
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(ApplicationsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ApplicationsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ApplicationsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Applications", 
    typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(Window1), 
    new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

Then, where you want to add it, you'll do something like this:

```
this.Applications = new ObservableCollection<string>();
Applications.Add("Whatever");
```

Finally, for the "simple" binding syntax to work in the XAML, I usually change the `DataContext` in my Window (or the root Control element for the file, whatever I'm working in) to

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ... >
   ...
```

Your Applications box will update automatically.

Comment: Thanks. It works, but only musst be set the listbox datacontext=this or ElementName=window in {Binding}.

Comment: You don't need to make your collection you are binding to a dependency property - as long at it's an ObservableCollection and the type in the collection implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your property value hasn't changed. It's still the same list, same reference.

One solution might be that your collections are of type `ObservableCollection`. These lists provide events for WPF when you add or remove items.